# Dimension too large with \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I want to define `varafterglowepsdown`, `varafterglowa` and `varafterglowb` and use them in a tikz function like this:

```
\newcommand{\varafterglowepsdown}{0.0001}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\varafterglowb}{ln(\varafterglowepsdown) - ln(1 + \varafterglowepsdown)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\varafterglowa}{(1 + \varafterglowepsdown) / exp(\varafterglowb)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    % some function using varafterglowa, varafterglowb, and varafterglowepsdown
    }]
    % some axis definition
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However on the third line I get a "Dimension too large." error.

How do I properly define `varafterglowa`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complementary approach to [percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288518) would be to use the LaTeX3 FPU (this provides an IEEE 754 floating point implementation in an expandable form):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\protected\def\fpset#1#2{\edef#1{\fpeval{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\varafterglowepsdown}{0.0001}
\fpset{\varafterglowb}{ln(\varafterglowepsdown) - ln(1 + \varafterglowepsdown)}
\fpset{\varafterglowa}{(1 + \varafterglowepsdown) / exp(\varafterglowb)}
\varafterglowa

\end{document}
```

The result here is a 'pure' number so should be usable where `pgf` needs a number. You can use `fpeval` directly in many places rather than store the result.

Comment: What does the `\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n` line do?

Comment: @RobertHegner In `expl3` syntax `_` and `:` are 'letters'. To let us access the command `\fp_eval:n` with a 'document' name I've made a copy of it as `\fpeval`: `\cs_new_eq:NN` does that (it's more-or-less `\let`).

Comment: @JosephWright I think it would be great if `\fpeval` and `\fpset` comes with the box with batteries included.

Comment: @percusse I've thought about that, but there are issues. One of the design aims for `expl3` is that as far as possible it keeps 'out of the way' in terms of existing documents. It adds _no_ document-level syntax on at design-level only `\ExplSyntax(On|Off)`, `\ProvidesExpl...` and `\GetdInfo`. So adding `\fpeval` would be 'risky'.

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe a math frontend as PGF parser might be a solution say a `pars3` package which offers the document level macros.

Answer (score 5):

There is a strict limitation in TeX about how big numbers can get which is plus minus 16384. Hence anything going above or anything that comes sufficiently close to zero in the divisor causes overflows. Here `exp(-9...)` is practically zero for TeX and it is done.

Instead you can use more precise calculation engines written for TeX for example `FP` or TikZ'  internal `fpu` library.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% Turn on the fp engine
\newcommand{\varafterglowepsdown}{0.0001}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\varafterglowb}{ln(\varafterglowepsdown) - ln(1 + \varafterglowepsdown)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\varafterglowa}{(1 + \varafterglowepsdown) / exp(\varafterglowb)}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}% Turn it off


\node{\pgfmathfloattofixed\varafterglowa\pgfmathresult};% Show the fixed number
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The downside with `fpu` is that you have to convert the results to the fixed notation from it's own float notation.